# Run multiple run configuration in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build-automation

I have created run configurations ( maven clean install , skip test ) in eclipse of projects in my eclipse workspace. They needs to be executed in particular order one after another. I've to run them manually one after another. Is there any way I can automate this ? Click one master configuration to run all maven build tasks at once ?

Comment: You can have multiple modules inside maven POM file.show what you tried with.

Answer (score 0):

> Click one master configuration to run all maven build tasks at once ?

Yes, this might be a solution.

When a simple project starts a simple configuration is usually enough. But when the complexity increases you end up in a too long build, so you start realizing that you don't want every goal runs on every build. At this point you have to choose how to handle such complexity: in general two approaches may be adopted:

- **one project many commands** : you might prefer keeping the project simple but with different goals / life-cycle phases / run configurations;
- **multi-module project one command**: you might prefer splitting your project in a multi-module project, with each module dedicated to a specific task (testing, building site, jar/war-ing), so you can run the same command but on a different module.